# How to print only the keys which have values?

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

I have a hash with keys and values as follows:

```
hash = {"lili" => [] , "john" => ["a", "b"], "andrew" => [], "megh" => ["b","e"]}
```

As we can see some of the keys have values as empty arrays.

Some keys have array values where there are actual values *in* the array.

I want to loop over the hash and generate a new hash that includes only those keys which have values in their arrays (not the ones which have empty arrays). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reject` to filter out those elements in your hash where the value is an empty array or the value is nil and then iterate to print their content;

```
{:lili=>[], :john=>[:a, :b], :andrew=>[], :megh=>[:b, :e], :other=>nil}
  .reject { (_2 || []).empty? }
  .each { puts "#{_1} has the value(s) #{_2}" }
```

that prints

```
john has the value(s) [:a, :b]
megh has the value(s) [:b, :e]
```

Comment: @MichaelB Works fine on my machine. Is it possible that you do not run the latest version of Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

### The title says:

**PRINT** only the keys, but reading the post you are trying to generate a hash subset given a hash.

The solution for the **TITLE** of the **POST**:

```
hash.each {|k,v| p k unless v.empty? }
```

---

If you want to generate a new hash subset give the original hash:

```
hash.reject { |k,v| v.nil? || v.empty? }
```

---

If you want to **PRINT** the subset generated give the original hash:

```
hash.reject { |k,v| v.nil? || v.empty? }.each { |k,v| p k }
```

Answer (score 1):

To return a hash that includes only entries which contains or have values (Non empty arrays or non nil values)

We can Simply do..

```
hash.reject {|k,v| v.blank?}
```

This will return

```
{"john"=>["a", "b"], "megh"=>["b", "e"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of your desired output or exact data structure, but you can simply use `reject` along with `empty?` to remove any `hash` value that contains an empty array:

```
hash = {"lili" => [] , "john" => ["a", "b"], "andrew" => [], "megh" => ["b","e"]}

hash.reject {|k, v| v.empty?}
#=>  {"john"=>["a", "b"], "megh"=>["b", "e"]}
```

It should however be noted that this approach will not work if any hash values are `nil`.  To address that situation, I would recommend either using `compact` to remove any hash elements with nil values prior to using `reject` **OR** by testing for either `nil?` or `empty?` (and in that order):

```
hash = {"lili" => [] , "john" => ["a", "b"], "andrew" => [], "megh" => ["b","e"], "other" => nil}

hash.reject {|k, v| v.empty?}
#=>  Evaluation Error: Ruby NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
hash.compact.reject {|k, v| v.empty?}
#=>  {"john"=>["a", "b"], "megh"=>["b", "e"]}

hash.reject {|k, v| v.empty? or v.nil?}
#=>  Evaluation Error: Ruby NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass    
hash.reject {|k, v| v.nil? or v.empty?}
#=>  {"john"=>["a", "b"], "megh"=>["b", "e"]}


hash.reject {|k, v| v.empty? || v.nil?}
#=>  Evaluation Error: Ruby NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass    
hash.reject {|k, v| v.nil? || v.empty?}
#=>  {"john"=>["a", "b"], "megh"=>["b", "e"]}
```

Comment: @Micheal Thank you for this. However, this seems a bit confusing. Is it possible for us to construct a new hash and transfer the records (only the ones which has values to keys) in the existing hash to that new hash?

Comment: @regularuser, I believe that's exactly what I've demonstrated.  Unless you can provide some better example of what you're looking for then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Can I do this - ?
```
  new_hash = Hash.new
```
```
  new_hash = hash.reject {|k, v| v.empty?}
```

Comment: All you need to do is assign the output to a new variable:  ```new_hash = hash.compact.reject {|k, v| v.empty?}```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!! So, in our case the new variable (i.e) new_hash is also a hash ? Sure, I will improve the question. Thankyou for the feedback

Comment: What does it look like?  You can also test it to find out:  ```new_hash.class #=> Hash```

Comment: I've tested it out by printing the keys & values like this 
```puts new_hash.keys ``` & ```puts new_hash.values``` . This is a hash! Thank you Micheal.

Comment: How about `hash.reject { |k,v| v.nil? || v.empty? }`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes, that works as well.  I had actually tried that and it was still producing an error but I see now that it was an order of operations thing.  I needed to test for nil before empty (i.e. ```v.nil? || v.empty?``` vs. ```v.empty? || v.nil?```).  Thanks.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @regularuser : Note that the proposed solution uses `reject`, not `reject!`. This means that your original hash is not modified.

Comment: @engineersmnky, safe navigation operator wouldn’t achieve the desired results and would instead leave key:value pairs with  nil values in the output hash.  The goal was to remove elements with nil values.

Comment: @MichaelB you are correct I apologize instead it would be `hash.select {|_,v| v&.any?}`

Comment: aa.reject {|k,v| v if v.empty? }.class returns a new instance of a Hash. And for the error on the `v.nil? || v.empty?` you can user `v.&nil? || v.&empty?`